# What wrong in the SELECT CODE?

Tags: mysql

Im trying to pull out only "completed" orders
whats the problem in this select code?

```
('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OrderUserID = :OrderUserID AND WHERE OrderStatus='Completed');
```

Comment: Using placeholders for both values would solve any quoting problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have a single quote before the `SELECT` and then two more around the `'Completed'`.

Replace the single quote at the start with a double, and put one at the end as well.

You also have an additional WHERE before your second condition. Normally you just say 'WHERE this AND this AND this'.

```
("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OrderUserID = :OrderUserID AND OrderStatus='Completed'");
```

Comment: can you send me exmple?

Answer (score 1):

The query only needs one "WHERE" clause, unless using subqueries.

```
(SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OrderUserID = :OrderUserID AND OrderStatus='Completed');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You AND the conditions when you want to have multiple constraints on the retreiving data.
`("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OrderUserID = :OrderUserID AND OrderStatus='Completed'");`